# Javascript event firing two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

To demonstrate my problem I have written this code.

> main.php

```
<body>
//some html
<script>
function fx1(){
   $(".elem").click(function(){
       alert("hello");
   })
}
</script>
//some html again
include sub-acc.php
</body>
```

> sub-acc.php

```
<script>
 fx1();
</script>
```

Now problem is that when I click on ".elem" button alert appears two time, i.e. event is fired two time how can I prevent this. Using jquerymobile as frontend framework.

Comment: How often is fx1() called. Because any time you call it one event listener for .elem is registered

Comment: Do you happen to have two nested elements with class elem? Or are you calling fx() again anywhere?

Comment: I tried out the code, and it only happens once.

Comment: fx1() is called one time only, one more thing Iam using jquerymobile as frontend framework

Comment: Set a breakpoint in browser to see the stack trace and find out where it's from

Comment: What versions of jQ and jQM are you using? It's recommended to bind events this way `.on('click', function....`. Without more details it's not possible to figure out the problem causing double binding, however, this can solve it `$('.elm').off('click').on('click', function () { code });`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define event listener that way and dont call fx1() anymore:

```
<body>
//some html

//some html again
include sub-acc.php

<script>

    $(document).on("click", ".elem", function(event){
       alert("hello");
    }); 
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: why should that change anything?